# Add data from an Excel spreadsheet to a word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, set

I am trying to add data from an Excel spreadsheet to a word document in Office 365 and I get runtime error 450 (Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.) The error occurs where I placed the arrow at `Set wdApp`. The word document opens, actually a template, and the desired text is pasted to a bookmark in the word document.

```
Sub Welcome()
MsgBox "Welcome to Math Worksheet Creator."

Dim NumberofQuestions As Integer
NumberofQuestions = InputBox("How many questions do want to create? You may select up to 50.")
If NumberofQuestions > 50 Then
        MsgBox "You cannot select more than 50 questions."
        NumberofQuestions = InputBox("Please select a maximum of 50 questions.")
End If

'Open a Word Template.

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
**-->Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")**


    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\VBA-Python\Worksheet Template.docm"
    End With


    Range("L4").Copy
    wdApp.Selection.GoTo wdGoToBookmark, , , "MathQuestion"
    wdApp.Selection.Paste
    
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="MathQuestion"
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wdApp = New Word.Application`.

Comment: Not a bad first post (by first post standards). You did a great job articulating your question. Friendly suggestion, use a title that describes your question so others searching for similar issues may find.  Good luck

Comment: (i see this just got changed by braX, but the OP should still know).